# Giving name to a loop

Tags: java, loops

While browsing questions and answers in this forum i found a piece of code were names were given to loops in order to use them for break. Like

```
nameofloop:
    for(){
        for(){
             if(){ break nameofloop;}
        }
    }
```

Im new to programming and i havent seen that before. My question is what other uses of naming loops are there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a labeled loop, is just a label that you place anywhere and then you  can "break" or "continue" to depending on your conditions. You can also use in a nested if-else with for loopings in order to break several loops decorated with if-else, so you can avoid setting lot of flags and testing them in the if-else in order to continue or not in this nested level.

Its use is discouraged as resembles a goto and causes spaghetti-code.

Personally I used only once, time ago, in order to break a for loop inside other two for loops with if-else and continue in the outer loop, as `break` inside a loop breaks this loop, but you continue in the outer loop, not the most-outer that was my case.

Comment: You cannot place it *anywhere*, only before statements (and it is only useful for statements which have other nested statements in them). (And `continue label;` is only possible if it was in fact a loop which got labeled.)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to illustrate the use.

Answer (score 10):

You can also say:

```
continue nameofloop;
```

...to jump to start of the named loop.  I don't think there are any other use cases for labels in Java.

Answer (score 7):

It's known as a labelled break which is a form of branching statement. You can see all the examples in the [Official Documention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 6):

Officially, I believe this is called a "labeled break". It's useful for breaking out of nested loops, such as:

```
found:
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; i++)
            if ( /* Some condition is met */)
                break found;
```

I don't think it's useful for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the only case it's used. And it's not something which is commonly used, because it's usually more readable to change the value of a flag to end a loop prematurely.

Answer (score -6):

1. Create an array (`int`) of size 10.
2. Let the user assign the values - (use for-loop).
3. Find the total and average of the values stored in the array - (use for- loop).

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?