# Is there a workaround for not being able to access static methods in an enum inside its constructor?

Tags: java, enums, static

I have an enum in which the elements all have unique IDs. In my constructor I throw an exception if there already exists an element with the given ID, like this:

```
public enum Number {

    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    private final int id;

    private Number(int id) {
        if (Number.isRegistered(id)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(id + " is already registered.");
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static Number getNumberFromID(int id) {
        for (Number n : Number.values()) {
            if (n.getID() == id) return n;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no number with the ID " + id);
    }

    public static boolean isRegistered(int id) {
        try {getNumberFromID(id);}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {return false;}
        return true;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

And in another class I try to reference this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number one = Number.getNumberFromID(1);
    }
}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Number.values(Number.java:1)
    at Number.getNumberFromID(Number.java:15)
    at Number.isRegisteredNumber(Number.java:23)
    at Number.<init>(Number.java:10)
    at Number.<clinit>(Number.java:3)
    ... 1 more
```

This isn't my exact code, which is why it seems a bit pointless, but it shows what I'm trying to do. From what I've found it seems that Java doesn't let you access static methods in an enum like this because it is still being constructed. Does anyone know a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `getNumberFromId` can't logically be called before the instances are created, because it's trying to use `Number.values()`, which iterates through the instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a static initializer to your class:

```
public enum Number {

    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    static {
      Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
      for (Number n : values()) {
        if (!seen.add(n.id)) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(...); 
        }
      }
    }

    private final int id;

    private Number(int id) { this.id = id }
}
```

Comment: This is one of those features of java you come across after years of experience with the language and say _that's a thing?_. Just like [labeled loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478951/giving-name-to-a-loop).

Comment: This should also work with defining `private static Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();` and putting the `if (!seen.add(id)) ...` into the enum constructor.

Comment: @codesimplicity no, you can't do that. You can't refer to static members from the enum constructor, because they would be initialized after the enum values.

Comment: @bkis never mind labelled loops: how about labelled *statements*: `foo: break foo;`; how about repeated assignment of a variable, with the same name as its type: `String String = String = String = "String";`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, `foo: break foo;` is kind of sad :(

Comment: @bkis sure. But it concisely illustrates the (not very widely-known) point that you can label more than loops.